# How to avoid compiler warnings when treating UITextField the same as UITextView

Tags: objective-c, protocols, compiler-warnings

Scenario:

I have two UITableViewCells containing a UITextField property and UITextView property respectively. Obviously both of these properties have properties in common, such as 'text' and 'textColor'

Objective:

Indiscriminately assign a string to the UITextField/UITextView's text property without raising compiler warnings. Can it be done?

Here's an example of what I'm doing:

Currently I do this to avoid compiler warnings:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
UITextField *textField;
UITextView *textView;
switch (indexPath.section) {
    case SectionDescription:
        textField = (UITextField *)[(TextFieldCell *)cell contents];
        textField.text = self.plan.description;
        break;

    case SectionNotes:
        textView = (UITextView *)[(TextViewCell *)cell contents];
        textView.text = self.plan.notes;
        break;
}
```

But I'd like to do something closer to this without the compiler warnings:

```
NSString *contents = [self getContents];

UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
UIView *textView = (?? *)[(?? *)cell contents];
textView.text = contents;
```

Is there a standard way to do this? I know if both objects conformed to a common protocol I could do something like "UIView  *textView = [cell contents];" Is there an answer to this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `[(id)textView setText:contents]`.

Comment: That works, although that obscures the meaning of the code. Is there any way to avoid that?

Comment: Not for this case. In the case of methods in the [UITextInputTraits protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html), which both UITextView and UITextField conform to, you could cast to `id<UITextInputTraits>` instead of just `id` to make your intent clearer.